# Is there a python assert() method which checks between two boundaries?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In some unit testing I'm currently doing, I need to pass a test when a variable lies between two boundary conditions.

Something like -

```
def myTest(self):
    myInt = 5
    self.assertBetween(myInt,3,8)
```

would pass the test. Or if myInt lied outside of the range 3 to 8 it would fail.

I've looked down the list of assert methods in the python documentation and can't work out which one would give me this sort of functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [assertTrue()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue) for that purpose:

```
self.assertTrue(myInt >= 3 and myInt <= 8)
```

Or, using Python's comparison chaining idiom:

```
self.assertTrue(3 <= myInt <= 8)
```

Comment: @agf, true, I always forget that idiom for some reason. Answer updated, thanks :)

Comment: The other side of this solution is, that it won't show you, what is the value of `myInt`. In case of error it will just show `False is not true`.
Thus I recommend using longer but more expressive pair of `assertLess` and `assertGreater`.

Answer (score 35):

[Frédéric's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7482883/68063) to use:

```
self.assertTrue(3 <= myInt <= 8)
```

results in test output like this:

```
AssertionError: False is not True
```

which gives the developer no clue as to what the problematic value of `myInt` actually was. It is better to be more long-winded:

```
self.assertGreaterEqual(myInt, 3)
self.assertLessEqual(myInt, 8)
```

because then you get helpful test output like this:

```
AssertionError: 21 not less than or equal to 8
```

If you find yourself using this idiom a lot, then you can write your own assertion method:

```
def assertBetween(self, value, min, max):
    """Fail if value is not between min and max (inclusive)."""
    self.assertGreaterEqual(value, min)
    self.assertLessEqual(value, max)
```

Note that if the value to be tested is known to be an integer, then you can use `assertIn` together with `range`:

```
self.assertIn(myInt, range(3, 9))
```

which results in test output like this:

```
AssertionError: 21 not found in range(3, 9)
```

Answer (score 10):

to complement the answer, you can add a msg to self.assertTrue and make it more readable

so

```
self.assertTrue(3 <= myInt <= 8, msg="%i is not between 3 and 8" % myInt)
```

would yield the right output and you wont need to do `assertGreaterEqual` and `assertLessEqual`.

Answer (score 2):

There is [assertAlmostEqual](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) which main use case is to compare floating point numbers. But with the `delta` parameter you can use it for ints:

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(9, 5, delta=3)
```

And this gives you meaningful error message:

```
AssertionError: 9 != 5 within 3 delta
```